# Eclipse J2EE "alt+shitf+z" didn't show the template i write

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I wrote a template like this:

[image]

It can change `abc` into `abd = function("abc")`.

When I select a parameter and press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> it doesn't appear.

[image]

When I select a statement and press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> it appears.

Please give me some advises on what steps I need to take in order to use my template when I press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Code templates help reduce typing time by inserting code into the editor. Each code template is given a short literal. Typing the literal into the editor window and press Ctrl + Space brings up a dialog box from which a code template associated with that literal can be selected.

So in your case to use your template just type `Val` (or all template name `ValueReplace`) and your template will show up in the list

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately it doesnt work.... And also, what I need is let it show up when i press "alt+shift+z".

Comment: Just tried in eclipse Mars and it's actually pretty straight forward just make sure you have created it with the right context. As for the shortcut you cant create one in 30 secs, you have to create a eclipse plugin for it